# What is the Vendor ID for Tablet Genesis?

Tags: android, hardware

Does anyone know the Vendor ID for USB debugging on Linux for Genesis Tablets? My tablet is the GT 7200. I need to debug with this tablet via USB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already got the answer, just need to run lusb on terminal and identify my Vendor ID e Product ID:

Bus 001 Device 019: ID 18d1:0003 Google Inc.

Where Vendor ID is: 18d1 and Product ID is: 0003